# Changing JButton Text Periodically

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I would like to create a JButton that changes its text periodically after the first click. I'm not really familiar with Swing library. What would be a good starting point? May I update its text without an action?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean to say when ever button is clicked it changes its text? or what?

Comment: No, I want to change text without a click, lets say every 2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you to change it on every fixed amount of time then you can use [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) or Thread to do this. But for this you have to listen at least one action so that you can initialize and start it.

You can also use [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) class from java.util like follow:

```
java.util.TimerTask timerTask = new java.util.TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //change button text here using button.setText("newText"); method
    }
};

java.util.Timer myTimer = new java.util.Timer();
myTimer.schedule(timerTask, 3 * 1000, 3* 1000); // This will start timer task after 3 seconds and repeat it on every 3 seconds.
```

Comment: so whenever my desired time comes, Do I need to repaint or just setText

Answer (score 3):

for all periodical events in Swing I only suggest [javax.swing.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

output by using [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) should be, for example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CrazyButtonTimer {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Crazy Button Timer");
    private JButton b = new JButton("Crazy Colored Button");
    private Random random;

    public CrazyButtonTimer() {
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 35));
        frame.getContentPane().add(b);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        javax.swing.Timer timer = new Timer(500, new TimerListener());
        timer.setInitialDelay(250);
        timer.start();
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        private TimerListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            Color c = b.getForeground();
            if (c == Color.red) {
                b.setForeground(Color.blue);
            } else {
                b.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CrazyButtonTimer crazyButtonTimer = new CrazyButtonTimer();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a timer ([here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) you can find some doc)

```
Timer timer = new Timer(100,this);
```

Your class has to extend action listener ed implements the following method which allow you to change the text of your `JButton`(I called it ``button).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if(e.getSource.equals(timer)){
    button.setText("newText");
  }
}
```

Luca

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers fail to mention how to update non-periodically. If you need it to update irregularly, you can make a method in your GUI class called something like: updateButton(); and just call that every time you want it to change your text.

```
public void updateButton(String newText)
{
     Button.setText(newText);
}
```

Just thought I'd add this in case someone wanted to set it irregularly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it periodically (e.g. every 5th second) you could create a new Thread which sets the text of the button to the desired value and repaints it (if necessary).